# Working on .json files (read/write/change) on-the-fly with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.8

Lately I started rewriting the game I wrote back in the days. My main concern was to try to fix its main issue being operating on single file (resulting in crashes and data overflow).

While conceptualising changes, I decided to use .jsons for storing data on-the-fly (as both "autosave" and material for regular saves done by user). I tried to use json library for creating functions that would make me easily read and write that data, going in such manner:

> read specific variable from .json ->  operate on it, if needed ->
> overwrite only that specific part of .json file

Sadly, no matter the way I do it, I can't get it even to read .json file, not even saying about editing the values. All "json.dump()" examples I found by far tries to write new lines to .json or replace file, but not simply edit specific value. I feel like rewriting whole file each turn of the game will be not efficient at all.

Code used by far (2 variants, both resulting in, respectively, no console output or use of _io.TextIOWrapper with which I have no idea how to convert into useful data):

```
def json_read(path, element):
  import json
  with open(path) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    data = dict(data[element])
    print (data)
```

```
def json_read(path, element):
  import json
  json_file = open(path, "r")
  print (json.load(json_file))
```

The main thing I want to achieve is to make function operating on four arguments, in simplified form looking like this:

```
def json_change(path, element, change_type, change_value):
  if change_type == "replacement":
    #replace .json variable [element] value with [change_value]
  elif change_type == "maths":
    #do mathematic equation (.json variable value [element] + [change_value]) and write its result back
  elif change_type == "var_addition":
    #write new variable called [element] in the end of .json file with value of [change_value]
```

Another function would be just trying to read the file from (path, element) arguments and it will return the value for further use by json_change or other elements. This one I already tried to introduce, as seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to just use the json library. Read the file once and do occasionally a save, let's say every five minutes.
Maybe you want to create a new class in a singleton pattern. This will ensure that you have one object that holds the current up-to-date information and only this object can update the file.

Here is a quick sketch on how this class may look like:

```py
# SaveFileHandler.py

import json


class _SaveFileHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = {}
        self._path = ""

    def read(self, path):
        self._path = path
        with open(path) as file:
            self._data = json.load(file)

    def write(self):
        with open(self._path) as file:
            json.dump(self._data, file)

    # now for every value you want data to have do the following
    # it allows you to check the value for errors and makes the usage more readable
    @property
    def key(self):
        return self._data["key"]

    @key.setter
    def key(self, value):
        self._data["key"] = value


# the is the only object you will ever use
save_file = _SaveFileHandler()
```

You can also read the save file directly in the init, this will make sure your data is always available.

Comment: Thank you! Although I found how to do this myself (using several functions) the way I wanted to, I really appreciate your solution and I feel like I can use it somewhere in the future.
Main problem of your suggestion of saving once a few minutes was that I did want my game to communicate with .json files as "root" of whole mechanics. Since it is turn-based, it will not make performance bad, and .jsons would keep all data that would need lots of variables if different way is used.
I will upload my solution as second answer (for anyone who would like to see it), but "best answer" goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out the solution myself, in precisely way I wanted to, here is my code I eventually used.

First of all, I decided to do two functions having similar system, yet serving different purpose (general save and load system for data; will show you only save one, since they differ only by directory they use).
Arguments as seen below:

- name = name of player (stored in "saves/X" folder)
- category = .json file used (there are four, each for different aspect of saving (stats/quests/world changes/inventory)
- dict_type = deciding whether returning value is dict containing all "variables" from save (True) or only chosen "variable" (False, default)
- element = specific "variable" (if dict_type = True, can be anything)

So in here I simply made function reading that specific file and returning either dictionary or "variable" itself. I also made safety gate for JSONDecoreError, so if .json (for some reason) is empty, it will print that.

```
def save_read(name, category, element, dict_type=False):
  import json
  final_path = "saves/" + name + "/in_use/" + category + ".json"
  data = {}
  try:
    with open (final_path) as json_file:
      data = json.load(json_file)
    if dict_type == False:
      return data[element]
    else:
      return data
  except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print ("JSON File: " + final_path + " does not have any arguments. Skipping.")
```

And code below is for more detailed management of "variables" within save file. It checks again player name, category and element (all being the same as above), but also have arguments:

- change_type = explaining the program what we want to do with function running (either replace value, make it relatively change, or even add new "variable" if new is needed)
- change_value = value we use, usually int, str or boolean

Therefore depending on "change_type" argument, "change_value" is used for different purposes (or not at all, if we make full save/load, explained at the bottom of this answer).

```
def save_change(name, category, element, change_type, change_value, in_use=True):
  #in_use=True is for all data elements within game, =False for saving game, since it uses different directory
  import json
  if in_use == True:
    final_path = "saves/" + name + "/in_use/" + category + ".json"
 
    #simply replacing value with new one (usually for string variables)
    if change_type == "replace":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element, True)
      temp_dict[element] = change_value
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)
 
    #math is intended to change value with +/- (use negative value to make it smaller)
    elif change_type == "math":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element, True)
      temp_dict[element] = temp_dict[element] + change_value
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

    #math, but for (*) [rare case]
    elif change_type == "math*":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element)
      temp_dict[element] = temp_dict[element] * change_value
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

    #math, but for (/) [rare case]
    elif change_type == "math/":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element)
      temp_dict[element] = temp_dict[element] / change_value
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

    #var_add is intended to be dict; can be useful with version_updater especially
    elif change_type == "var_add":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element, True)
      temp_dict.update (change_value)
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

    #var_add, but for deleting; change_value can be anything in this case
    elif change_type == "var_del":
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element, True)
      temp_dict.remove (element)
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

    #for loading the game (uses load_read)
    elif change_type == "game_load":
      temp_dict = load_read(name, category, element, True)
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)

  elif in_use == False:
    #for game saving | 'element' and 'change_value' can be anything
    if change_type == "game_save":
      final_path = "saves/" + name + "/" + category + ".json"
      temp_dict = save_read(name, category, element, True)
      with open (final_path,'w') as file:
        json.dump(temp_dict, file, indent = 2)
```

If you would like to see precise code for complete system (as of now), it is also possible to see on [latest working commit on GitHub](https://github.com/Toma400/The_Isle_of_Ansur/tree/9047451a51fe3f9a299284e5ff53d45fe265a9ce). It uses:

- system/json_manag.py - for general management (communication game <-> "save in use")
- system/save_system/save_load.py - for full save/load mechanics, run
  manually by player

It simply overwrites archive .jsons or "currently used by game" .jsons, depending whether it is load or save.